# devise form_for, how to use array of check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I use `acts-as-taggable-on` to save multiple user interests. I try to show a fixed list of checkboxes on the signup form. The code below works.

```
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
%p
  - ["music","art","movies"].each do |interest|
    = check_box_tag "user[interested_list][]", interest
```

Problem is that when hitting "Submit" and if page reload because some field was missing I do not see the checkboxes previously checked, They're all reset.

I understand I'm missing the value, but I been trying using something like this but it doesn't work

```
= check_box_tag "user[interested_list][]", interest, params[:user][:interested_list][interest]
```

I get the following error

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I just needed to check if the value was present inside the array.

```
= check_box_tag "user[interested_list][]", interest, session[:interested_list].include?(interest)
```